# create file after positive exception FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, file, parsing, csv

I have written script that parses a web page and saves data of interest in a CSV file. Before I open the data and use it in a second script I check if the file with data exist and if not I am running the parser script first. The odd behaviour of the second script is, that it is able to detect that there is no file, then the file is created, but when it is read for the first time it is empty (part of else statement). I tried to provide some delay by using the time.sleep() method, but it does not work. The explorer clearly shows that the file is not empty, but at the first run, script recognizes the file as empty. At the subsequent runs the scripts clearly sees the file and is able to properly recognize it content.

Maybe You have some explanation for this behaviour.

```
def open_file():
    # TARGET_DIR and URL are global variables.
    all_lines = []

    try:
        current_file = codecs.open(TARGET_DIR, 'r', 'utf-8')

    except FileNotFoundError:
        procesed_data = parse_site(URL)
        save_parsed(procesed_data)
        compare_parsed()
        open_file()

    else:
        time.sleep(10)
        data = csv.reader(current_file, delimiter=';')

        for row in data:
            all_lines.append(row)
        current_file.close()

        return all_lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some recursion going on.

Another way to do it—assuming I understand correctly—is this:

```
import os

def open_file():
    # TARGET_DIR and URL are global variables.
    all_lines = []

    # If the file is not there, make it.
    if not os.path.isfile(TARGET_DIR):
        procesed_data = parse_site(URL)
        save_parsed(procesed_data)
        compare_parsed()
        # Here I am assuming the file has been created.

    current_file = codecs.open(TARGET_DIR, 'r', 'utf-8')
    data = csv.reader(current_file, delimiter=';')
    for row in data:
        all_lines.append(row)
    current_file.close()
    return all_lines
```

Comment: Thank You, when I do it in the way shown above it works. It seams that exception are not able to handle the recursion. The question is why, but I do not have required python knowledge to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

you should return the result of your internal `open_file` call, or just opening the file in your except block:

```
def open_file():
    # TARGET_DIR and URL are hopefully constants
    try:
        current_file = codecs.open(TARGET_DIR, 'r', 'utf-8')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        procesed_data = parse_site(URL)
        save_parsed(procesed_data)
        compare_parsed()
        current_file = codecs.open(TARGET_DIR, 'r', 'utf-8')

    data = csv.reader(current_file, delimiter=';')
    all_lines = list(data)
    current_file.close()
    return all_lines
```

Comment: And hopefully not a dir,

Comment: Ok, the solution does not work. The main thing is why the call of open_file() does not work properly when used in the except block.

Comment: @totoro; Sorry the name of variable TARGET_DIR is somehow missleading. It is path to the file.

Comment: @Daniel. After first run the content of the file was shown as None.

Comment: @frankot: that was the behaviour of your code. So mine should work.